# Loading Captcha image form a site does not work

Tags: python, php, python-requests, captcha

I am trying to collect Captcha images using the Python requests module and save them to file or load in memory for further processing, but nothing works as below.

Code so far, I tried.

```
import requests
url = 'https://dpdc.org.bd/site/application/libs/captcha/simple-php-captcha.php?_CAPTCHA&t=0.84582400+1651208314'
r = requests.get(url)

with open('file.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

The site I am working with [URL](https://dpdc.org.bd/site/service/ebill_gov/-)

N.B. I tried with `request.Session()` too, but all went in vain. I am trying to avoid heavy-weight Selenium though selenium can do the job. I will save the Captcha image and solve it using Keras, but I am halted at the Captcha image collection step.

Comment: "nothing works" means ... what exactly?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz `updated the question`

Comment: is there a problem with the request? or is the response invalid? or empty? What do you expect and what do you actually get? We are outstanders, so you'd have to give exact details on _everything_ (related to your problem *edited) as we cannot read your screen or your mind.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz even you can not load captcha from the captcha url mentioned above if you enter that url in address bar.

Comment: I'd suggest you'll get in touch with the admin of that website to clarify, why the URL doesn't return any content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAPTHA generates by PHP script that requires a session.

You need to execute 2 requests: 1 for the cookie, 2 for the image with first request cookie.

```
import requests


form_url = 'https://dpdc.org.bd/site/service/ebill_gov/';
form_response = requests.get(form_url)

# missing code to parse captcha url
# ...

captcha_url = 'https://dpdc.org.bd/site/application/libs/captcha/simple-php-captcha.php?_CAPTCHA&t=0.22003900+1651258878'
captcha_response = requests.get(captcha_url, cookies=form_response.cookies)

with open('file.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(captcha_response.content)
```

Comment: Let me check with keras if it works considering cookie, loaded captcha etc. stuffs. Fantastic! How you deduced this way to proceed with?

Comment: Just looked in the browser how it works.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer.